# javascript how to pass function results into the same function along with a value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have a function called `findLCM`, which takes 2 arguments (a,b).

I also have an array with an unknown number of elements (all numbers). For the purpose of explanation let's say:

```
var values = [c, d, e, f]
```

now what I need to build is this:

```
var result = findLCM(findLCM(findLCM(c,d),e),f);
```

I tried to write a for loop that would do this, but got stuck and can't figure it out. Can somebody point out the correct way to do this?

My code so far:

```
var result = 0;    

for(f = 0; f < values.length -2; f++) {
  result *= findLCM(findLCM(values[f], values[f+1]),values[f+2]);
}
```

Comment: sorry, updated the question. The issue is that I need to write the result of the final function I'm trying to build onto a variable, but can't really figure out how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a good case to use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce):

```
var values = [c, d, e, f];
var lcm = values.reduce(function(previous, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
    return findLCM(previous, currentValue);
});
alert(lcm);
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking is to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce).

```
var findLCM = function(a,b) {
  ...
};

var result = [a, b, c, d, e].reduce(findLCM);
```

Comment: @LostMyGlasses answered some minutes before me, congrats for the quick response ;)

Comment: yes, but your answer is a single line of code, while he took the long way. Both work tho, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this recursive function

```
function findLCMArray (arr)
{
  if ( arr.length > 2 )
  {
     return findLCM( arr.shift() , findLCMArray (arr) );
  }
  else
  {
     return findLCM( arr.shift(), arr.shift() );
  }

  function findLCM( x, y )
  {
    //logic to do LCM
  }
}
```

Or you can loop through like this

```
var arr = [2,4,6,8];
var lcmValue = arr[0];
arr.forEach ( function(value){

  lcmValue = findLCM( lcmValue, value);

} );
alert(lcmValue);
```

Comment: Check the `if` branch in your `findLCMArray` function. And the `.forEach()` is the complicated alternative to an `.reduce()` :)

Comment: @Andreas agree about `reduce` :)

Comment: @Andreas thanks, correct it now. I was calling the wrong function.